# What is the role of watching articulation in learning pronunciation?

Tags: terminology, language-acquisition, articulation

It's obviously easier to pronounce and, perhaps even acquire, a sound or sequence not present in one's native language if one watches carefully a speaker's mouth. What is this phenomena called? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: As far as anyone is aware, children blind since birth acquire language (including its phonology) with as much facility as those who are not. So it probably plays no role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root phenomenon is known as [*the **motor theory** of **speech perception***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_theory_of_speech_perception).

(In computing the technique is called [*audio-visual speech recognition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio-visual_speech_recognition).)

As it pertains to learning:
Pronunciation is the result of muscle movements.  Different pronunciations require different muscle movements, just like any other physical activities.  The muscles physically develop with practice, as does the brain's ability to coordinate them.  As to why seeing it done properly can help, it is not so different than learning to kick a ball with a certain technique.

More reading:
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_reading
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McGurk_effect
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory